# Docker try to download unnecessary busybox image on creation of redis pod with kubernetes tools

Tags: redis, docker, coreos, kubernetes

I'm trying to make a demo of [Kubernetes](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes) on [CoreOS](https://coreos.com/blog/running-kubernetes-example-on-CoreOS-part-1/) cluster. I have a pod with redis specifications as:

**redis.json**

```
{
  "id": "redis",
  "desiredState": {
    "manifest": {
      "version": "v1beta1",
      "id": "redis",
      "containers": [{
        "name": "redis",
        "image": "dockerfile/redis",
        "ports": [{
          "containerPort": 6379,
          "hostPort": 6379
        }]
      }]
    }
  },
  "labels": {
    "name": "redis"
  }
}
```

Then, when I execute command `/opt/bin/kubecfg -h http://127.0.0.1:8080 -c kubernetes-coreos/pods/redis.json create /pods` the output take a infinity minutes.

Then I execute on other console: `journalctl -f -xn -u kubernetes-apiserver -u etcd -u kubernetes-kubelet -u docker` and output it's:

```
Aug 11 09:33:22 core-01 docker[1036]: 2014/08/11 09:33:22 GET /containers/json
Aug 11 09:33:22 core-01 docker[1036]: [2ac127cf] +job containers()
Aug 11 09:33:22 core-01 docker[1036]: [2ac127cf] -job containers() = OK (0)
Aug 11 09:33:22 core-01 docker[1036]: 2014/08/11 09:33:22 GET /containers/json
Aug 11 09:33:22 core-01 docker[1036]: [2ac127cf] +job containers()
Aug 11 09:33:22 core-01 docker[1036]: [2ac127cf] -job containers() = OK (0)
Aug 11 09:33:22 core-01 docker[1036]: 2014/08/11 09:33:22 POST /images/create?fromImage=busybox
Aug 11 09:33:22 core-01 docker[1036]: [2ac127cf] +job pull(busybox, )
Aug 11 09:33:24 core-01 docker[1036]: 2014/08/11 09:33:24 GET /containers/json
Aug 11 09:33:24 core-01 docker[1036]: [2ac127cf] +job containers()
Aug 11 09:33:24 core-01 docker[1036]: [2ac127cf] -job containers() = OK (0)
Aug 11 09:33:33 core-01 docker[1036]: 2014/08/11 09:33:33 GET /containers/json
Aug 11 09:33:33 core-01 docker[1036]: [2ac127cf] +job containers()
Aug 11 09:33:33 core-01 docker[1036]: [2ac127cf] -job containers() = OK (0)
Aug 11 09:33:34 core-01 docker[1036]: 2014/08/11 09:33:34 GET /containers/json
Aug 11 09:33:34 core-01 docker[1036]: [2ac127cf] +job containers()
Aug 11 09:33:34 core-01 docker[1036]: [2ac127cf] -job containers() = OK (0)
Aug 11 09:33:44 core-01 docker[1036]: 2014/08/11 09:33:44 GET /containers/json
Aug 11 09:33:44 core-01 docker[1036]: [2ac127cf] +job containers()
Aug 11 09:33:44 core-01 docker[1036]: [2ac127cf] -job containers() = OK (0)
Aug 11 09:33:54 core-01 docker[1036]: 2014/08/11 09:33:54 GET /containers/json
Aug 11 09:33:54 core-01 docker[1036]: [2ac127cf] +job containers()
Aug 11 09:33:54 core-01 docker[1036]: [2ac127cf] -job containers() = OK (0)
Aug 11 09:34:03 core-01 docker[1036]: 2014/08/11 09:34:03 GET /containers/json
Aug 11 09:34:03 core-01 docker[1036]: [2ac127cf] +job containers()
Aug 11 09:34:03 core-01 docker[1036]: [2ac127cf] -job containers() = OK (0)
Aug 11 09:34:04 core-01 docker[1036]: 2014/08/11 09:34:04 GET /containers/json
Aug 11 09:34:04 core-01 docker[1036]: [2ac127cf] +job containers()
Aug 11 09:34:04 core-01 docker[1036]: [2ac127cf] -job containers() = OK (0)
Aug 11 09:34:14 core-01 docker[1036]: 2014/08/11 09:34:14 GET /containers/json
Aug 11 09:34:14 core-01 docker[1036]: [2ac127cf] +job containers()
Aug 11 09:34:14 core-01 docker[1036]: [2ac127cf] -job containers() = OK (0)
Aug 11 09:34:24 core-01 docker[1036]: 2014/08/11 09:34:24 GET /containers/json
Aug 11 09:34:24 core-01 docker[1036]: [2ac127cf] +job containers()
Aug 11 09:34:24 core-01 docker[1036]: [2ac127cf] -job containers() = OK (0)
Aug 11 09:34:33 core-01 docker[1036]: 2014/08/11 09:34:33 GET /containers/json
Aug 11 09:34:33 core-01 docker[1036]: [2ac127cf] +job containers()
Aug 11 09:34:33 core-01 docker[1036]: [2ac127cf] -job containers() = OK (0)
Aug 11 09:34:34 core-01 docker[1036]: 2014/08/11 09:34:34 GET /containers/json
Aug 11 09:34:34 core-01 docker[1036]: [2ac127cf] +job containers()
Aug 11 09:34:34 core-01 docker[1036]: [2ac127cf] -job containers() = OK (0)
Aug 11 09:34:44 core-01 docker[1036]: 2014/08/11 09:34:44 GET /containers/json
Aug 11 09:34:44 core-01 docker[1036]: [2ac127cf] +job containers()
Aug 11 09:34:44 core-01 docker[1036]: [2ac127cf] -job containers() = OK (0)
Aug 11 09:34:54 core-01 docker[1036]: 2014/08/11 09:34:54 GET /containers/json
Aug 11 09:34:54 core-01 docker[1036]: [2ac127cf] +job containers()
Aug 11 09:34:54 core-01 docker[1036]: [2ac127cf] -job containers() = OK (0)
Aug 11 09:35:03 core-01 docker[1036]: 2014/08/11 09:35:03 GET /containers/json
Aug 11 09:35:03 core-01 docker[1036]: [2ac127cf] +job containers()
Aug 11 09:35:03 core-01 docker[1036]: [2ac127cf] -job containers() = OK (0)
Aug 11 09:35:04 core-01 docker[1036]: 2014/08/11 09:35:04 GET /containers/json
Aug 11 09:35:04 core-01 docker[1036]: [2ac127cf] +job containers()
Aug 11 09:35:04 core-01 docker[1036]: [2ac127cf] -job containers() = OK (0)
Aug 11 09:35:14 core-01 docker[1036]: 2014/08/11 09:35:14 GET /containers/json
Aug 11 09:35:14 core-01 docker[1036]: [2ac127cf] +job containers()
Aug 11 09:35:14 core-01 docker[1036]: [2ac127cf] -job containers() = OK (0)
Aug 11 09:35:24 core-01 docker[1036]: 2014/08/11 09:35:24 GET /containers/json
Aug 11 09:35:24 core-01 docker[1036]: [2ac127cf] +job containers()
Aug 11 09:35:24 core-01 docker[1036]: [2ac127cf] -job containers() = OK (0)
Aug 11 09:35:30 core-01 docker[1036]: Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/busybox/images: dial tcp 107.22.52.107:443: connection timed out
Aug 11 09:35:30 core-01 docker[1036]: [2ac127cf] -job pull(busybox, ) = ERR (1)
Aug 11 09:35:30 core-01 docker[1036]: 2014/08/11 09:35:30 POST /containers/create?name=k8s--net--redis--50c36965
Aug 11 09:35:30 core-01 docker[1036]: [2ac127cf] +job create(k8s--net--redis--50c36965)
Aug 11 09:35:30 core-01 docker[1036]: No such image: busybox (tag: latest)
Aug 11 09:35:30 core-01 docker[1036]: [2ac127cf] -job create(k8s--net--redis--50c36965) = ERR (1)
Aug 11 09:35:30 core-01 docker[1036]: [error] server.go:1025 Error making handler: No such image: busybox (tag: latest)
Aug 11 09:35:30 core-01 docker[1036]: [error] server.go:90 HTTP Error: statusCode=404 No such image: busybox (tag: latest)
```

**Why docker try to pull busybox if I never reference that image?**  I appreciate any idea or collaboration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker is pulling the busybox image to support our network container. (I believe that's since been updated to a custom, very tiny image.)